# Remove any spaces between ' ' in cell array Matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have this cell array

```
aitransp = 

Columns 1 through 14

'27'    '26'    '25'    '24'    '23'    '22'    '21'    '20'    '19'    '18'    '17'    '16'    '15'    '14'

Columns 15 through 21

'13'    '12'    '11'    ' 9'    ' 8'    ' 7'    ' 1'
```

As you can see, the last 4 elements have a space between the ' ', such as ' 9'. 
Is there any way to remove any spaces occurring between '' in a cell array?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Use `strtrim`  .

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html

Comment: in that case I would have to convert the cell array to string right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [*`strtrim`*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html), you don't have to convert to string

```
strtrim(aitransp)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions for greater flexibility:

```
result = regexprep(aitrasp, '(^\s*)' , '');         %// remove only leading space
result = regexprep(aitrasp, '(^\s*)|(\s*$)' , '');  %// remove leading or trailing space
result = regexprep(aitrasp, '\s' , '');             %// remove any space
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ii = 1:numel(aitransp)
    aitransp{ii}(aitransp{ii} == ' ') = '';
end
```

This should do the trick.